# Scalar products(dot product) in terms of $\lambda$

Tags: calculus, vectors

After spending a solid day or two on vectors, particularly Scalar/Dot products. I come across one of the questions that doesn't quite match the same *format* I find online. Before continuing, I'll post the actual question:

---

### With respect to origin *O*, the position vectors of points A, B and C are:

$$a = \lambda i + 2j -k, b = 3i + 4j -2k, c = 5i - j +2k$$
Respectively, $\lambda$ is a constant.

- (a) Find the scaler product $\vec{BA} . \vec{BC}$ in terms of $\lambda $

---

There's a whole(much larger) question proceeding that, however I would like to atleast try tackling it myself first before asking.

The first issue I've personally had was, $\lambda$. I've never come across it in a vector before, none of the vectors have had a variable so I would always find something like $b$ and $c$ however I'm positive it's just me overthinking all of it.

I've worked around with dot product and most of the time used equations:
$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{\vec{BA}.\vec{BC}}{\left|\vec{BA}\right|\left|\vec{BC}\right|}$$

Or

$$\vec{BA}.\vec{BC} = \left | \vec{BA} \right |\left | \vec{BC} \right |\cos(\theta)$$

Amongst a few other situational ones

---

The question itself holds little to no points so I presume I'm overdoing what I need to do, spending 10 minutes each revision and not coming with a concrete answer is definitely not the way to go.

---

The final small question I would like to ask in relation to this is how $a = \lambda i + 2j -k, b = 3i + 4j -2k, c = 5i - j +2k$

Is related to $\vec{BA}.\vec{BC}$

---

### Attempts so far:

(a)I first found all the values for $\vec{OA}$, $\vec{OB}$, $\vec{OC}$ which were:

- $\vec{OA} = ( \lambda , 2, -1)$
- $\vec{OB} = ( 3, 4, -2)$
- $\vec{OC} = ( 5, -2, 2)$

I then using one of the provided answers used those to find values for $\vec{BA}$ and $\vec{BC}$ like so:
$$\vec{BA} = \vec{OA} - \vec{OB} $$
Therefore:
$$(\lambda, 2, -1) - (3, 4, -2) = (\lambda - 3, -2, 1)$$

And did the same for $\vec{BC}$. The answers boiled down to:
$$(\lambda-3, -2, 1).(2, -5, 4)$$

Thus: $(2\lambda + 8)$ seems to be the answer

---

I do not wish to ask for a final answer, but more of a guideline on how to achieve it

Comment: Hint: $b=3i+4j-2k$ means that the coordinates of B are $(3,4,-2)$. Likewise for the other points, one $(A)$ having a parameter. You can easily deduce the vector coordinates as well from the points. And then you can do the scalar product of the two vectors from their coordinates.

Comment: Alright that clarification alone should be more than enough. Thanks!

Comment: Also if someone could comment the final answer(not how they got there) would be great in order to compare and see if I did right

Comment: Final result: $\lambda^2-8\lambda+6$

Comment: @Martigan Thanks alot!

Comment: I have added my attempt in working it out

Comment: Sorry! I did the wrong scalar product, woth AB and AC, not BC...

Comment: No problem at all @Martigan. Stuff that happens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec{BA}=\vec{A}-\vec{B}=(\lambda,2,-1)-(3,4,-2)=(\lambda-3,-2,1)$

Comment: How does $\vec{BA} = \vec{B} - \vec{A}$

Comment: It is a short notation for $\vec{BA}=\vec{OA}-\vec{OB}$. You can check it graphically.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't realise that, thanks!

Comment: So after I've found both $\vec{BA}$ and $\vec{BC}$ I then simply substitute there values from $\vec{BA}.\vec{BC}$ or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: Thanks alot Steven, I'm sorry if I'm taking your time. Could I kindly ask you to review my attempt posted on the question itself, I used your following method and all is well however the last piece of the puzzle doesn't seem right. Thanks a million in advance

Comment: The scalar product is $(\lambda-3, -2, 1)\cdot(2, -5, 4)=(\lambda-3).2+10+4=2\lambda+8$

Comment: You're one of a kind, that cleared everything up!

Comment: You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hints; $$\vec{OA}=(\lambda, 2, -1), \vec{OB}=(3, 4, -2), \vec{OC}=(5, -1, 2)$$
You can find $\vec{BA}$ and $\vec{BC}$ from here. When you have coordinates, it's convenient to use the vector representation I used.

Comment: Yep this is great, I figured the vector values but wasn't QUITE sure whether $a = λi + 2j -k$ was equivalent to $\vec{OA}$

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the other definition of "standard scalar product" in this context?

I mean other than the $\cos (\theta)$-stuff?

The $i$, $j$, and $k$ are the base vectors, I suppose? Then you should be able to write the scalar product as $(a-b) \cdot (c-b)$ where the $\cdot$ refers to the scalar product an $a$, $b$, and $c$ are as in your text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does indeed, will be posting my answer soon enough, $i, j, k$ are meant to represent values for $x, y, z$ if I'm not mistaken. I've had to implement something a while ago for such in actual matrices

Comment: $i, j, k$ are the unit vectors, they just point at a direction and have $||\cdot||=1$.

Comment: @Martigan: How do you get to the square of $\lambda$? I think, $\lambda$ should occur only in first order.